# Google Docs drawings to Visio

Tags: microsoft-visio, google-docs, flowchart

Is there a way to export drawings made with Google Docs to Visio? Maybe through some other software. I can see that Lucidcharts supports both Google Drive and export to Visio, but does it actually support opening drawing file made in Google Docs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's see which file formats are shared between the two if we are moving data from Google Docs to Visio!

---

Google Docs' supported [export file formats](https://support.google.com/docs/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=49115) for Drawings:

- PDF Document (.pdf)
- **Scalable Vector Graphics (.svg)**
- **PNG image (.png)**
- **JPEG image (.jpg)**

Visio's supported [import file formats](https://office.microsoft.com/en-us/visio-help/file-formats-that-you-can-import-into-a-visio-drawing-HP085050844.aspx):

> - AutoCAD Drawing File Format (.dwg, .dxf)
> - Compressed Enhanced Metafile (.emz)
> - Enhanced Metafile (.emf)
> - Graphics Interchange Format (.gif)
> - **JPEG File Interchange Format (.jpg)**
> - **Portable Network Graphics (.png)**
> - **Scalable Vector Graphics Drawing (.svg, .svgz)**
> - Tag Image File Format (.tif, .tiff)
> - Windows Bitmap (.bmp, .dib)
> - Windows Metafile (.wmf)

---

So, we can use the following file formats: SVG, PNG, or JPEG. With drawings, you'd want to work with [vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_graphics) rather than [raster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raster_graphics) graphics, so you're left with **SVG**.

Answer (score 3):

I tried using the svg export and then importing into Visio, but Google Draw does not seem to create a svg file which is usable in Visio. It's a single object which can't be ungrouped.

Comment: This should go as a comment because it does not actually answer OP's question.

Comment: Well it is an answer, and the answer is "no" you can't export to Visio if you want to edit them.

Answer (score 0):

[Lucidchart](https://www.lucidchart.com) also supports .svg import and you can export a diagram from Lucidchart in Visio format (.vdx). Hopefully that is helpful.

Comment: Please disclose in your answer that you are the marketing director for the software (otherwise, it could be considered spam).  Using a paid charting product for the sole purpose of translating files between two other applications, when the svg file format is already readable by both other applications without the need for Lucidchart, makes no sense.  However, this does reply to a direct question about the product, although the answer does not mention that the product adds no value to the process.

Comment: Lucidchart SVG import functionality is limited. The result is "shapes", not diagrams. These can't be ungrouped or edited. I also lost all my text on import.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it to a svg, jpeg, etc. but you can't convert to vdx. I also don't think a lot of people know about Google Drawings and Microsoft Visio.